# Dynamic column selection with CsvHelper - how to get a dynamic ClassMap

Tags: c#, csv, dynamic, csvhelper, expandoobject

My application based on CsvHelper has a use case to dynamically choose the columns to be read from a csv file and store their values into lists of records. I would like to be able to define for instance how the column values should be converted, similarly to the ClassMap concept from CsvHelper. Would be possible to build a class with properties that model the record containing the selected columns "on-the-fly"? For each property the property name should be defined from a string based on the name of the selected column, and the property  Type describing the type of the data in that column for the property Type?
I mean something like this to describe the columns:

```
"Name", typeof(string)
"Age", typeof(int)
"Address", typeof(string)
"LoanInterestRate", typeof(double)
"LoanExpirationDate", typeof(DateTime)
...
```

Would be then possible to define a CsvHelper ClassMap for such a dynamically created class?
I found some samples using the ExpandoObject, but there is no mapping used.

Comment: Would something like the answer to this question be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177675/generic-types-in-registerclassmap-with-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I actually solved the problem by dynamically creating at runtime the type of the class used for mapping.